# saving record in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am new to node.js and mongoDB. I have been following book on the subject which works successfully. However, when I tried to practice the learning... it fails while saving the record.

Can you please guide me in my initial learning step please?

I confirm that node.js and mongoDB is installed and running....

my code page …

```
var mongo = require('mongoose');
const UserSchema = new mongo.Schema({
    name: {
      type: String,
      trim: true,
      required: 'Name is required'
    },
    email: {
      type: String,
      trim: true,
      unique: 'Email already exists',
      match: [/.+\@shetty\.org\.uk/, 'Please fill a valid email address for your domain only'],
      required: 'Email is required'
    },
    hashed_password: {
      type: String,
      required: "Password is required"
    },
    status: {
      type: String,
      enum: ['New','Active','Disabled','Banned'],
      default: "New"
    },
    salt: String,
    updated: Date,
    created: {
      type: Date,
      default: Date.now
    }
});

var User = mongo.model('User', UserSchema);
var user1 = new User({
    name: 'Avinash',
    email: 'avinash@shetty.org.uk'
});

var user1 = new User({
    name: 'Avinash',
    email: 'avinash@shetty.org.uk'
});

mongo.promise = global.promise;
mongo.connect('mongodb://localhost/mongotest',{useNewUrlParser: true});

console.log(user1);

user1.save((err, result) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log('Error while saving');
    }else{
        console.log("Successfully saved record!");
    }
});
mongo.disconnect();
```

the console.log outputs this ….

```
$ node index.js
{ status: 'New',
  _id: 5bb8ca9a348028b4d4663544,
  name: 'Avinash',
  email: 'avinash@shetty.org.uk',
  created: 2018-10-06T14:45:46.348Z }
Error while saving
(node:46292) DeprecationWarning: collection.ensureIndex is deprecated. Use createIndexes instead.
```

Please do guide... :(

Comment: A good way to start is to log the error you're getting, that way it will be much easier to help.

Comment: I am getting this error

Comment: { MongoError: server instance pool was destroyed
    at basicWriteValidations (C:\development\mongo\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\topologies\server.js:700:41)
    at Server.insert (C:\development\mongo\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\topologies\server.js:805:16)
    at Server.insert (C:\development\mongo\node_modules\mongodb\lib\topologies\topology_base.js:321:25)

Comment: Ok, I posted an answer below to why that Error may be showing up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `save()` method is asynchronous, which means that your code will continue to run the next instruction before the async one is finished.

Right after the save call you're executing `mongo.disconnect()` which will kill your instance, before `save()` is finished.

**Solution:**

Don't call `mongo.disconnect()` until after the `save()` operation is finished and your callback has been executed.

**Additional errors:**

I also notice that you've declared the `hashed_password` property of the user schema as required, while not providing a password when creating an instance of `user`. This will cause the validation to fail.

Comment: To add to this answer: you shouldn't be calling `mongo.disconnect()` at all unless something seriously wrong has occurred. Mongo is able to handle it's own connection, and as long as it is working as expected, let it do exactly that.

Comment: Thanks a million. I forgot the key fact that javascript is Async :)